# How to open a opj file in python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization

I am trying to open an opj (from Origin, the data visualization tool) in python but I haven't been able to find a way to know if it's even possible. I downloaded PyWavefront to give it a shot but it seems that it was directed to Blender files instead, which are also opj apparently.

Comment: Wavefront/Blender use `.obj`, not `.opj`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [this project](https://github.com/Saluev/python-liborigin2), although you have to compile the tool yourself.